# Making a backup copy of SQL table throws me this error: "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; "

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a backup of my table in MySql but I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table `zbackup_oc_t_city` from `oc_t_city` LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

This is the code that I'm using to backup

```
SELECT * INTO TABLE `zbackup_oc_t_city` FROM `oc_t_city`
```

Here is my `oc_t_city` table:
[image]

Here is `zbackup_oc_t_city`
[image]

I have tried it on numerous tables and it keeps throwing me the same error... any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @juergend thanks for reply, I have just tried it and it still throwing me same error. I typed this `select * from 'oc_t_city' into table 'zbackup_oc_t_city'` (forces me to declare table) and it gives me exactly same error

Comment: Why not use standard backup processes?

Comment: @Strawberry how does that work? I searched online and the query above is what multiple forums said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create your backup table and do the backup in just one statement use

```
CREATE TABLE `zbackup_oc_t_city` SELECT * FROM `oc_t_city`;
```

> [CREATE TABLE ... SELECT Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-select.html)
>
> You can create one table from another by adding a SELECT statement at
>   the end of the CREATE TABLE statement:
>
> CREATE TABLE new_tbl [AS] SELECT * FROM orig_tbl;

With MySQL you can't use [SELECT ... INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html) to select into a new table:

> SELECT ... INTO Syntax
>
> The SELECT ... INTO form of SELECT enables a
>   query result to be stored in variables or written to a file:
>
> SELECT ... INTO var_list selects column values and stores them into
>   variables.
>
> SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE writes the selected rows to a file. Column and
>   line terminators can be specified to produce a specific output format.
>
> SELECT ... INTO DUMPFILE writes a single row to a file without any
>   formatting.

Comment: +1 RTFM and a link to TFM. Exactly what the error message says: *check the manual*

Comment: thanks again for the answer and the explanation. That makes much more sense!

Answer (score 0):

I do remember having similar troubles while working with SQL myself. One cause of error I found was the use of citation marks... try removing the citation marks like this:

```
SELECT * INTO zbackup_oc_t_city FROM oc_t_city;
```

I'm not sure this fixes your problem (but I can't see anything else wrong with your query). I hope it does though. :)

Comment: thansk for reply. Yeah it is odd, I tried capitals/lowercase and kept throwing me an error. Not having the best time with SQL but at least I managed to get the backup on:)